# Can't run Selenium PhantomJS instances in parallell

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm using Selenium's node.js API to run PhantomJS instances against a series of web pages. The code I use to execute the actions on the pages work fine, but it seems only one instance of Selenium/PhantomJS can run at a time. This function is called multiple times from the same module and steps through pages in a webshop where the pagination is handled client side (which is why I need the Selenium/PhantomJS environment - to extract data from each page).

Once again, the code in and of itself works fine, but it can't execute in parallell. What could be causing this?

```
module.exports = function (crawler, page, parsePage, done) {
    "use strict";

    var _ = require("lodash"),
        format = require("util").format,
        path = require("path"),
        webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver"),
        By = webdriver.By,
        until = webdriver.until;

    var phantomPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../node_modules/.bin/phantomjs"),
        isWin = process.platform === "win32";

    var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .withCapabilities({
            "phantomjs.binary.path": isWin ? phantomPath + ".cmd" : phantomPath
        })
        .forBrowser("phantomjs")
        .build();

    var windowHandle = new webdriver.WebDriver.Window(driver);
    windowHandle.setSize(1100, 1000);

    var getAllPagesContent = function (driver) {
        var pagesContent = [],
            pageNo = 1;

        var getNextPage = function () {
            var nextPageLink;

            return driver.findElements(By.css(".pagination li")).then(function (elements) {
                return elements[elements.length - 1];
            }).then(function (element) {
                nextPageLink = element;
                return element.getAttribute("class");
            }).then(function (className) {
                return _.includes(className, "active");
            }).then(function (isLastPage) {
                return (!isLastPage) ? driver.getPageSource() : false;
            }).then(function (content) {
                if (content)
                    pagesContent.push(content);

                content && console.log("Got page %d", pageNo++);

                return nextPageLink.findElement(By.css("a")).then(function (element) {
                    return element.click();
                }).then(function () {
                    return driver.wait(until.stalenessOf(nextPageLink), 10 * 1000);
                }).then(function () {
                    return content ? getNextPage() : pagesContent;
                });
            });
        };

        return getNextPage();
    };


    var processTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("PhantomJS for page %s took too long to execute", page.url);
        driver.quit().then(done);
    }, 60 * 1000);

    driver.get(page.url).then(function () {
        var pageOverlay = driver.findElement(By.css("#overlay-the-new"));

        return pageOverlay.isDisplayed().then(function (visible) {
            if (visible) {
                pageOverlay.click();
                return driver.wait(until.elementIsNotVisible(pageOverlay), 10000);
            }
        }).then(function () {
            return getAllPagesContent(driver);
        });
    }).then(function (contents) {
        clearTimeout(processTimeout);
        console.log("Got %d pages for %s", contents.length, page.url);

        _.forEach(contents, function (pageContent) {
            parsePage(page.url, pageContent);
        });

        return driver.quit();
    }).then(function () {
        done();
    });
}
```

Comment: have you specified for it to run in parallel in your options

Comment: Not explicitly, no. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Although PhantomJS is now deprecated you can still run it in parallel isolated [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) containers by using [Selenoid](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid). There is a ready to use image with latest release here: https://hub.docker.com/r/selenoid/phantomjs/tags/

Answer (score 0):

Parallel execution with Selenium tends to be done using [Remote WebDrivers](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriver) and the Selenium [Grid2 Framework](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2).

This tutorial at [WeDoQA](http://blog.wedoqa.com/2013/07/how-to-run-parallel-tests-with-selenium-webdriver-and-testng-2/) seems to be the sort of thing you want. At a brief glance it has each test in a separate class, while a central test base class points towards Grid2's hub, which then (in the tutorial) executes the tests in parallel using a Firefox driver. You could easily retool this to use phantomjs, but you might have to rework your test structure.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but do you know how this translates to my node.js environment? It feels like I shouldn't have to start a Java VM that manages my Selenium code just to run more than one Selenium instance in parallel...

Comment: Afaik using Selenium Grid's Hub is the only way to easily do parallel tests on the same browser, past that I'm not sure. I did find this package [wd-parallel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wd-parallel) but do not know if that would be any help. Sauce labs seem to use wd.js/WebDriver.js and have a section on running in [parallel](https://docs.saucelabs.com/tutorials/node-js/#running-tests-in-parallel).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're only using one driver.  I'd initialize a second driver, then use threading to run in parallel.  I think this could get the job done.

Answer (score -1):

Use Thread for running in parallel or you can use any test framework which can take care of running the tests in parallel.

Comment: That is not an answer. Provide details